# Alfresco and google drive like authorization

Tags: authorization, alfresco

I would like to authorize certain web-apps (In my case: diagram.ly) to access my Alfresco repository like google drive for creating and modifying files. Is there some Alfresco extension out there that already does that? How difficult would it be to write such a "Do you allow XY to access your files" dialog for Alfresco?

Comment: Can you not just use CMIS as the way for your application to talk to Alfresco, then either supply the far end with your Alfresco credentials, or a ticket if you only want a short authorisation period?

Comment: @Gagravarr I will take a closer look at the source code behind diagram.ly if the ticket approach could work. I have not used CMIS before but I heard interesting things so its certainly worth a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The on-premise version of Alfresco generally requires you to authenticate using a username and password, although it is possible as a developer to plug in other authentication mechanisms if you know what you're doing.

If you're after more of an OAuth-type solution that avoids the need to authenticate directly, you could register for an Alfresco Cloud account. The public API for that service, featuring OAuth2-based authorization, was launched this week.

See https://developer.alfresco.com/cloud for more details.

Comment: Alfresco Cloud is not an option at the moment as the Alfresco instance is behind the companys firewall and only accesible from the intranet.

Comment: If your Alfresco instance is behind a firewall then how do you expect diagram.ly to be able to access it, then?

Comment: The engine behind diagram.ly is open source (http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) and we would run it on our own server.

Comment: In that case you would need to use an Alfresco username and password to connect from jgraph to Alfresco. As @Gagravarr suggests you should use the CMIS API unless you have a specific reason to use something else.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the best way